# Building multi-line strings, programmatically, in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Here's something I often do when programming:

```
code = ''
code << "next line of code #{something}" << "\n"
code << "another line #{some_included_expression}" << "\n"
```

**Is there some better way than having `<< "\n"` or `+ "\n"` on every line?** This seems quite inefficient.

I'm interested in Ruby solutions, in particular. I'm thinking something like

```
code = string.multiline do
  "next line of code #{something}"
  "another line #{some_included_expression}"
end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This would be one way:

```
code = []
code << "next line of code #{something}"
code << "another line #{some_included_expression}"
code.join("\n")
```

Comment: you can lose the variable:
`["first line", "second line"].join("\n")`

Answer (score 30):

If you're looking to build a block of text, the easy way to do it is to just use the % operator. For example:

```
code = %{First line
second line
Third line #{2 + 2}}
```

'code' will then be

```
"First line\n second line\n Third line 4"
```

Comment: +1. Also just for those reading up on this you don't need to use %{string}... any character will do. For example %-string- or %~string~

Answer (score 9):

Use <<- operator:

```
code = <<-CODE
var1 = "foo"
var2 = "bar"
CODE
```

Comment: This looks pretty good (I guess it's a HERE document), but it preserves white space at the beginning of the lines. any way to get rid of that?

Comment: `code = <<-CODE.gsub(/^\s+/,'')` followed by the heredoc as usual.

Comment: close, but I want it to preserve indentation, too... it's just the *extra* whitespace that should be gone. yep, I know a workaround, but it's ugly.

Comment: Why would you want to preserve indentation in HEREdoc? o0

Answer (score 5):

It would work for you to just embed ...\n" in your strings, I suppose. Here is a fun way to do it:

```
class String
  def / s
    self << s << "\n"
  end
end
```

then

```
f = ""           # => ""
f / 'line one'   # => "line one\n"
f / 'line two'   # => "line one\nline two\n"
f / 'line three' # => "line one\nline two\nline three\n"
```

This would enable something like:

```
"" / "line 1" / "line 2" / "line 3" # => "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n"
```

Or even:

```
f/
"line one"/
"line two"/
"line three"     # => "line one\nline two\nline three\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method presented [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=683059&seqNum=3):

```
str = <<end.margin
  |This here-document has a "left margin"
  |at the vertical bar on each line.
  |
  |  We can do inset quotations,
  |  hanging indentions, and so on.
end
```

This is accomplished by using this:

```
class String
  def margin
    arr = self.split("\n")             # Split into lines
    arr.map! {|x| x.sub!(/\s*\|/,"")}  # Remove leading characters
    str = arr.join("\n")               # Rejoin into a single line
    self.replace(str)                  # Replace contents of string
  end
end
```

I guess the question with this is: does the lack of portability / presence of monkey patching make this solution bad.

Comment: Instead of having to put a "  |" prefix for each line AND also changing the String class, why not just use "code << " as in my answer.  You can shorten the 'code' variable name to be 'd'.  It's easy to understand and any Ruby programmer should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with:

```
code = "next line of code #{something}\n"+
       "another line #{some_included_expression}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place your multi-line text in a file, and use ERB to parse it (note ERB is included with Ruby)

```
require 'erb'

multi_line_string = File.open("multi_line_string.erb", 'r').read
template = ERB.new(multi_line_string)
template.result(binding)
```

(ERB can access variables from a Binding, an object that provides access to the instance methods and variables that are owned by another object. By setting it to "binding" it points to itself)

Documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html).